# How to force library to use androidX constraintlayout instead of android.support constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-databinding, androidx

I'm implementing the Android [Layer-xdk library](https://docs.layer.com/xdk/androidxdk/upgrade_guide)  and I've run in to a bit of a snag.  When I build I get the following error:

`error: cannot find symbol public final android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout root;`

The error is caused by a generated class in the layer library called `XdkUiMessageModelVhDefaultVBinding.java`

and this is the line causing the error:

`public final android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout root;`

If you hover over ConstraintLayout, which is red, it says "Cannot resolve symbol ConstraintLayout."

This class is generated by Android databinding library from the xml `xdk_ui_message_model_vh_default.xml`

which is using an androidX contraint layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/xdk_ui_message_model_vh_avatar_padding"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/xdk_ui_message_model_vh_avatar_padding"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/xdk_ui_message_model_vh_avatar_padding"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/xdk_ui_message_model_vh_avatar_padding"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/xdk_ui_message_model_vh_padding"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/xdk_ui_message_model_vh_padding"
    android:duplicateParentState="true" android:tag="layout/xdk_ui_message_model_vh_default_0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

oddly the constraint layout is the root element. I had thought the `<layout>` needed to be the root element with a `<data>` sibling to the root UI layout stuff in order for the Binding class to be generated properly.  I may have misunderstood that part though.

Is there a way I can force whatever builds or generates the code to use androidX?

Or if any one has any clarifying info on what is causing the issue,  I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Seems like the library needs to be updated to use a provided ConstraintLayout or simply use Android X itself :/ Seems like you don't have access to the source code, so bug them to update it! :)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini  That's what I thought at first but the `FragmentChatListBinding` class is actually generated code.  so I believe they didn't actually write that class android studio did.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you add these two lines to your `gradle.properties` file AS will look after the compatibility issues for you and make the library work with your code regardless of them being using androidx or not.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

[image]